# Flot chart tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using Flot interactive chart, the data being displayed is taken in from a datatable.

When the user hover's over a point the tooltip displays "Height(cm) on 6.00 = 168", basically the "168" represents the y value which is correct as it corresponds with the y-axis labels.
However the "6.00" should be a date, as is displayed on the chart along the x-axis, "6.00" is the sequence number , I need to get the label.....
any ideas ?

```
   //Show ToolTip Part 2
            function showTooltip(x, y, contents)
            {
                $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css(
                    {
                        position: 'absolute',
                        display: 'none',
                        top: y + 5,
                        left: x + 15,
                        border: '1px solid #333',
                        padding: '4px',
                        color: '#fff',
                        'border-radius': '3px',
                        'background-color': '#333',
                        opacity: 0.7
                    }
                ).appendTo("body").fadeIn(400);
            }

            //Show ToolTip Part 1
            var previousPoint = null;
            $("#VitalsChart").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item)
            {
                $("#x").text(pos.x.toFixed(2));
                $("#y").text(pos.y.toFixed(2));

                if (item)
                {
                    if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex)
                    {
                        previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

                        $("#tooltip").remove();
                        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
                            y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);



                        showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, item.series.label + " on " + x + "=" + "<strong>" + y + "</strong>");


                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    previousPoint = null;
                }
            });

            //Plot Data
            var plot = $.plot($("#VitalsChart"), [{ data: weight, label: "Weight (kg)" },
                                                  { data: height, label: "Height (cm)" }],
            {
                series:
                    {
                        lines:
                            {
                                show: true,
                                lineWidth: 2,
                                fill: false,
                                fillColor: { colors: [{ opacity: 0.5 }, { opacity: 0.1 }] }
                            },

                        points: { show: true },

                        shadowSize: 7
                    },

                grid:
                    {
                        hoverable: true,
                        clickable: false,
                        tickColor: "#ddd",
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        minBorderMargin: 10
                    },

                colors: ["red", "blue"],

                xaxis:
                    {
                        ticks: xLabels,
                        tickDecimals: 0
                    },

                yaxis:
                    {
                        ticks: 11,
                        tickDecimals: 0
                    }
            });
        }
```

Comment: How are you defining `xLabels`? You can probably index into that: `var x = xLabels[item.datapoint[0]]`

Comment: Nice one Matt, thats looking much better, added the following        var x = xLabels[item.datapoint[0] - 1],  it is printing the correct date but also the sequence number in front of it....

Comment: xlabel definition..in js file                                      var xAxisData = data.xLabels.map(function (obj)
                {
                    return [parseInt(obj.sequence, 10), obj.date];
                });

Comment: and in the controller... var xAxisResult = (from a in model
                               select new
                               {
                                   sequence = ++i,
                                   date = a.RecordedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
                               }).ToList();                      return Json(new
            {
                xLabels = xAxisResult,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var x = xLabels[item.datapoint[0] - 1][1];
```

Your ticks (`xLabels`) is an array of 2 element arrays. You need just the second element, the label itself.

Comment: Similar solution, that worked for me:
`item.series.data[item.dataIndex][0]`
I have to say I do use the 'categories' plugin, don't know if that makes it behave differently.